# Трансляция HLS или MPEG-DASH потока на сайт

Tags: nginx, ipc, rtmp, hls

Очень нужна помощь в осуществлении трансляции rtsp потока с камер на сайт, столько всего перепробовал — не получается вывести поток на страницу сайта на Wordpress. Нужен взгляд со стороны на все мною проделанное, буду благодарен любым советам и подсказкам!

Есть некий сайт работающий на хостинге с SSL на Wordpress, на этот сайт нужно опубликовать живую трансляцию с 4х IP камер. Перелопатив хренову тучу материала в сети понял, что есть два реальных варианта, HLS и MPEG-DASH. Причем MPEG-DASH в некоторых случаях требует перекодирования потока, а так как ПК для ретрансляции не шибко мощный, то HLS выглядит интереснее, но в целом задача запустить хоть что-то.

Для ретрансляции был установлен NGINX 1.18.0 на свежий Manjaro, собран с модулем nginx-rtmp от sergey-dryabzhinsky (https://github.com/sergey-dryabzhinsky/nginx-rtmp-module) , конфиг настроен по мануалу,раньше с NGINX дела не имел, больше использовал Apache. Так же уточню, что сервер для ретрансляции находится за натом, через Iptables были проброшены порты для http и для rtmp (были попытки опубликовать rtmp трансляцию на сайт).

И так, все готово, все настроено! Проверка через VLC внутри сети показала, что все работает, поток запустился! Запуск из вне дался хуже, если я находясь внутри сети пытаюсь открыть поток через VLC по внешнему адресу, например http://196.96.186.86:8080/cams/stream1.m3u8, то ничего не откроется, если этот же адрес запросить снаружи, то поток запускается, я так понимаю, что проблема где-то в правилах Iptables, устранить эту проблему мне пока не удалось, но поскольку запрашивать поток будет сайт, который находится снаружи, я решил этот вопрос отложить напоследок.

Следующий этап, попытка вставить поток на сайт. Испробовав кучу разных плееров типа FV Player, Videojs, … запустить поток на сайте так и не получилось, все плееры выдают какую-то ошибку, причем некоторые говорят, что возможно формат не тот, а другие пишут, что проблема с сетью. Но VLC же нормально запускает поток! В чем может быть проблема? Случайно попал на информацию, что если сайт использует https (именно по этому я упомянул SSL в начале), то и поток должен использовать https, а у меня NGINX вообще висит даже без домена на белом IP, кто сталкивался с этим, есть ли разница по какому протоколу будет идти поток? Для проверки этой теории, я перевел весь сайт на хостинге на http, получил кучу страшных предупреждений, но сайт теперь, так сказать, на одной волне с сервером ретрансляции, все используют http. Но чуда не произошло, плееры на странице так и не показали поток, повторюсь, VLC же отлично все показывает.

Позже, совершенно случайно увидел, что Firefox на Android, именно на телефоне, запустил HLS поток с сайта!! При этом на ПК в Firefox или Сhromium поток не запускается, так же поток отказался запускаться и в Chrome на телефоне, WTF?!! Наверное это позволяет снять вопрос о разности протоколов полностью и скорее всего указывает на проблемы в конфиге NGINX, вот только в чем может быть проблема…

ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО тем, кто дочитал до этих строк! Куда двигаться? Почему при любых раскладах, будь то трансляция в HLS или MPEG-DASH, с транскодированием или нет VLC все нормально показывает, а на странице сайта одни ошибки, кроме Firefox на Android?

Заранее спасибо всем отозвавшимся!!!

Ниже мой конфиг nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  auto;

load_module /etc/nginx/modules/ngx_rtmp_module.so;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    types_hash_max_size 4096;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   /tmp;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
rtmp_auto_push on;
rtmp {
        live on;
        #dash on;
        hls on;
        hls_fragment 5s;
        server {
                listen 1935;
                application cams {
                hls_path /tmp/cams;
                #dash_path /tmp/cams;
                }
                #exec_static ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.0.117/user=admin&password=pass&channel=1&stream=0.sdp? -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -c:a aac -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/cams/stream1;
                exec_static ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.0.117/user=admin&password=pass&channel=1&stream=0.sdp? -c copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/cams/stream1;
                exec_static ffmpeg -i rtsp://admin:pass@192.168.0.250/onvif1 -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/cams/stream2;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

сам промудохался, пока не стал перетыркивать js плееры, первый вариант заработал на jw он спок играет rtmp но замудохался прикручивать вариант именно на html5 без флэша, воткнул videojs c модулем hls играет нормуль кручу для тестов две камеры и ролик с мультиком

Comment: Да, videojs лучше всего подходит под это дело!

Comment: К сожалению, у меня не получается вывести, работает только на пк: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1369758/423786

Answer (score 0):

### Проблемы было две. Добрые люди помогли найти ответ.

#### Проблема номер 1:

Разность протоколов. 
Если сайт работает по https, то видео поток так же должен быть по https. В моем случае это лишний головняк, так как ретрансляция видео крутится на собственном сервере, так что проблему решил созданием отдельной страницы для трансляции видео по протоколу http.

#### Проблема 2:

В конфиг nginx нужно добавить опцию

> add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

Эта опция указывает какому домену разрешена трансляция вашего видео, * - означает любому.

Должно это выглядить вот так:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;        
    add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin,Range,Accept-Encoding,Referer,Cache-Control';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Server,Content-Length,Content-Range,Date';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, HEAD, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1369758/423786